# how to post list data in string or int data in rest api from angular formData

Tags: arrays, angular, django-rest-framework, rest, form-data

I was posting data from angular formData to django rest API but I am getting an error  `"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."`

here how I am sending data by using form data

```
let noticeData = this.announceForm.value;
if (noticeData.students.includes('all')){
    noticeData.students = noticeData.students.filter((s) => s != 'all')
}
noticeData.students = JSON.stringify(noticeData.students);
```

not working I need some way to send this data in string or int format

Comment: Don’t stringify stuff maybe?

Comment: Yes I tried already not working

Comment: It needs to be string or int not list

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use FormData if you don't have to send files. FormData accepts only strings and files in general. Use Json objects instead.

Comment: i have to send file i need to pass list element as sting in form data and i have to formData  since it is more convinient